# Grammar- "be placed in"

Tags: passive-voice

The sentence is "He advised that **she be placed** in the one available incubator."

Could somebody explain why there is she be placed? is it passive voice?

Comment: other verbs that work like this: recommend, suggest, etc.

Answer (score 3):

'That she be placed' uses the **subjunctive mood**. We can use the subjunctive in two main instances: wishes or hypotheses, and imperatives. For an imperative (a necessity, a suggestion, or an imperative action), we form the expression using 'that' and the bare infinitive of a verb:

> Necessity: it is essential that Peter **send** the money today.
>
> Suggestion: he advised that the baby **be** placed in the incubator.
>
> Imperative: the police require that he **show** his licence

[The subjunctive tense in English (Cambridge)](https://blog.cambridgecoaching.com/what-is-the-subjunctive-tense-in-english)

Note that many native speakers are unaware of the correct use of the subjunctive (or even its existence), or, if they are, consider it old-fashioned. In today's casual speech it is very common to use the [indicative mood](https://web.archive.org/web/20220824164654/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/moods) in places that require the subjunctive. In the examples above you would often hear people say 'that Peter sends', 'that the baby is placed', and 'that he shows his licence'. The [Oxford Living Dictionary](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825045104/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive) says that it is acceptable but frowned upon to put the indicative in writing, even though many people do not apply the subjunctive in everyday informal speech.

Comment: Being subjunctive doesn't prevent it from being passive.  An active-voice restatement is easy to find: "He advised that *someone* place her in the one available incubator."

Comment: wow! that's some very deep sh*t that clears a lot in my head, thank you